# jQuery slideDown and slideUp submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown, slideup

I have a small problem with the jQuery functions slideUp and slideDown.

## *[jsBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/odegik/edit#javascript,html,live)*

I have a vertical menu with underneath it a vertical submenu.

When the user enter a menu item which has a submenu it must show it, This is the part which is working.

When the user leaves the menu item and goes to the submenu item it still needs to be visible.
This problem i tried to catch with a setTimeout function that will remove (slideUp) the submenu after 1500ms. If the user moves his mouse to the submenu in that time the setTimeout will be cleared (clearTimeout)

But when the user moves his mouse fast over the main menu items all the submenu's will be shown and the content from the orginal page will be pushed down.

Image: http://i43.tinypic.com/5ww8yq.png

This is when i moved my mouse very fast over all the main menu items.

How it should be:
When a user moves his mouse to a main menu item, the submenu must be shown. When he moves to a other main menu item the current submenu must be invisible and the other submenu must be shown.

```
#menu
{
        background-color: white;
        width: 1000px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        height: 30px;
        position: relative;
}
#menu ul li
{
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        width: 125px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li.right { float: right; }
#menu ul li a
{
        top: 5px !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 30px;
        color: #01224D;
}
.submenu
{

        background-color: #01224D;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 30px;
        color: white;
        display: none;
}
.submenu ul li
{
        display: inline;
        width: 100px;
        height: 30px;
        line-height: 30px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
}
.submenu ul li.right { float: right; }
.submenu ul li a
{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 30px;
        color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                        <a class="mainMenuA" id="menu-1" href="#">Lederwaren</a>
                </li>
                <li><a class="mainMenuA" id="menu-2"  href="#">Tassen</a></li>
                <li><a class="mainMenuA" id="menu-3"  href="#">Koffers</a></li>
                <li><a class="mainMenuA" id="menu-4"  href="#">Kleding</a></li>
                <li><a class="mainMenuA" id="menu-5"  href="#">Accessoires</a></li>
                <li class="right"><a href="vestigingen.php">Vestigingen</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- menu-->
<div class="submenu" id='submenu-1'>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- submenu -->
<div class="submenu" id='submenu-2'>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- submenu -->
<div class="submenu" id='submenu-3'>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- submenu -->
<div class="submenu" id='submenu-4'>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- submenu -->
<div class="submenu" id='submenu-5'>
        <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        </ul>
</div><!-- submenu -->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                var timer;
                var hover;
                $('.mainMenuA').hover(
                    function()
                    {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
                        $('#submenu-'+id).slideDown();
                    },
                    function()
                    {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
                        timer = setTimeout(function() { $('#submenu-'+id).slideUp(); },1500);
                    }
                );
                $('.submenu').hover(
                    function()
                    {
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                    },
                    function()
                    {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id');
                        timer = setTimeout(function() { $('#'+id).slideUp(); },1500);
                    }
                );
            });
```

I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using timer use `stop` function to stop the current animtion

http://api.jquery.com/stop/

e.g:

```
$('.mainMenuA').hover(function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('#submenu-'+id).stop().slideDown();
},function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
      $('#submenu-'+id).stop().slideUp();
});
```

Use the parameters of `stop` if needed for best result.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide any .submenu elements that are showing, before you show the new one.  I tried 2 different methods - using hide() and using slideUp().  I personally prefer the slideUp() method as seen in this jsfiddle....

http://jsfiddle.net/DgqS4/

Comment: This have the same problem i has, when you move fast over the menu items

Answer (score 0):

When you show a submenu, add a `class` like `submenu-open` to it, this will be used to to find and hide it if necessary.
Code for function on hover:

```
$('.submenu-open').stop().hide().removeClass('submenu-open');
var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
$('#submenu-'+id).addClass('submenu-open').slideDown();
```

This should easily resolve your issue, tested it in your jsBin demo!

Comment: With this example when i move my mouse fast over the items it still shows me all the submenu underneath eachother

Comment: @WannaKnow I reordered the function chain, now it should work!

Answer (score 0):

well not sure whether you are open to this solution or not but i would suggest you to make some changes in HTML as well reason being you are anyways creating submenu divs and if i understood your question right then u don't want the page content to move i.e u can have specific height made available for the submen below the main menu (which should be 30px in your case).

Here's the solution which I would suggest and hope it is of help to you,

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>DEMO</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>



     <div id="menu">
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="mainMenuA">
                            <a id="menu-1" href="#">Lederwaren</a>
                            <div class="submenu" id='submenu-1'>
                                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                            </div><!-- submenu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainMenuA">
                        <a id="menu-2"  href="#">Tassen</a>
                        <div class="submenu" id='submenu-2'>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div><!-- submenu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainMenuA">
                        <a id="menu-3"  href="#">Koffers</a>
                        <div class="submenu" id='submenu-3'>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div><!-- submenu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainMenuA">
                        <a id="menu-4"  href="#">Kleding</a>
                        <div class="submenu" id='submenu-4'>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div><!-- submenu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="mainMenuA">
                        <a id="menu-5"  href="#">Accessoires</a>
                        <div class="submenu" id='submenu-5'>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </div><!-- submenu -->
                    </li>
                    <li class="right"><a href="vestigingen.php">Vestigingen</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div><!-- menu-->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
      menu, nav, section { display: block; }
      #menu
    {
            background-color: white;
            width: 1000px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            height: 30px;
            position: relative;
    }
    #menu ul li
    {
            float: left;
            display: inline;
            width: 125px;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            text-align: center;
    }
    #menu ul li.right { float: right; }
    #menu ul li a
    {
            top: 5px !important;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            height: 30px;
            color: #01224D;
    }
    .submenu
    {

            background-color: #01224D;
            width: 1000px;
            /*height: 30px;*/
            color: white;
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
    }
    .submenu ul li
    {
            display: inline;
            width: 100px;
            /*height: 30px;*/
            line-height: 30px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
    }
    .submenu ul li.right { float: right; }
    .submenu ul li a
    {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 20px;
            /*height: 30px;*/
            color: white !important;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var openSubMenu;
    $('.mainMenuA').hover(function(){
          openSubMenu = $('.submenu', $(this));
          openSubMenu.css({height: '30px'});
          openSubMenu.stop().slideDown();

    },function(){
          openSubMenu.stop().slideUp();
    });
});
```

Note: I've created the submenu div inside the 'li' element so that we don't have to write hover event to the submenu divs. I'm assigning hover events to the 'li' element itself, i'm also assigning height to the submenu before slideDown to avoid race conditions in animation

Here's the working example http://jsbin.com/odegik/4/edit